# When do integrals converge, but absolute values of integrals not converge?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples

With reference to exercise 3 on page 34 of this: http://courses.mai.liu.se/GU/TATM85/Solomon%20-%20Measure%20Theory%20and%20Lebesgue%20Integration.pdf

The exercise asks to show that if $f_n$ is a series of integrable functions on $E$, then$\int_E |f-f_n| \to  0 \iff \int_E|f_n| \to \int_E|f|$.

Pleas note I am not asking for a solution to this exercise, just an example related to it.

I was wondering if anyone could provide an example of why we need the absolute values on the left, to help me understand it more intuitively. Could someone please provide an example of a sequence of $f_n$ that are measurable on $E$, and some function $f$ where
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_Ef_n = \int_Ef$$ but $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_E|f_n-f| \neq 0$$
Thank you!

Comment: If a sequence of real number $x_n$ satisfies $|x_n|\to |a|$, does that imply $x_n\to a$?

Comment: No, because we could have $x_n \to -a$ or $x_n$ might not even converge. How can I use this to construct a sequence of functions?

Comment: think of some sequence of constant functions.... indeed you can choose all functions to be the same...

Comment: Ohhh.. Thank you! Haha, now it seems like a dumb question.

Comment: Sorry, out of curiosity, does it also hold for $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_E |f_n| = \int_E f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E = \Bbb{R}$, $f_n(x) = \sin(nx) 1_{[-\pi,\pi]}(x)$.  (i.e. The sine curve on $[-\pi,\pi]$).  By symmetry, $\int_E f_n = 0$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, so take $f \equiv 0$, so that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_Ef_n = \int_Ef$.  Since $$\int_E |f_n - f| = 2n \int_0^{\pi/n} \sin(nx) dx = 2[-\cos(nx)]_0^{\pi/n} = 4,$$ $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_E|f_n-f| = 4 \neq 0$.

The above calculations also answers the question in the comment:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_E |f_n| = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_E |f_n - f| = 4 \ne 0 = \int_E f.$$

[Graph on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hkvzpvcbhh)